# Pip broken after installing requests[security]

Tags: python, debian, pip

After running
`pip install requests[security]`
Running any pip command outputs the error below. I've tried apt-get removing and reinstalling python-pip as well as python-pyopenssl. Wondering if anyone has advice or has ran into this problem? I can't upgrade python or Debian and would like to get pip working again.

Debian 6.0.10
Python 2.6.6
python-pip 1.5.6

```
$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 305, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2244, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 49, in <module>
    from ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification import SUBJ_ALT_NAME_SUPPORT
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ndg/httpsclient/ssl_peer_verification.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ndg.httpsclient.subj_alt_name import SubjectAltName
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ndg/httpsclient/subj_alt_name.py", line 102, in <module>
    class AnotherName(univ.Sequence):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ndg/httpsclient/subj_alt_name.py", line 105, in AnotherName
    namedtype.NamedType('value', univ.Any().subtype(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Any'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this by simply doing:  `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the removal didn't magically happen with `sudo apt-get autoremove`.  Of course I also tried the standard `pip uninstall ndg-httpsclient` with no luck first.

In the end, I had to go into the python program directory and forcibly removing it.

```
$ cd usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
$ sudo rm -rf ndg_httpsclient-0.3.3-py2.7.egg-info
$ sudo rm -rf ndg_httpsclient-0.3.3-py2.7-nspkg.pth
$ sudo rm -rf ndg
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this bug here:  https://github.com/cedadev/ndg_httpsclient/issues/5

> I suspect the problem is that pip on Ubuntu is using ndg_httpsclient, and the current ndg_httpsclient conflicts with the
>   old pyasn1, so pip breaks during installation.
>
> Anyway, valid versions of pyasn1 to choose from are : 0.0.9a0,
>   0.0.10a0, 0.0.11a0, 0.0.12a0, 0.0.13a0, 0.0.13b0, 0.0.13, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9
>
> And I have found a semi-reasonable workaround to the problem.
>
> However 0.0.13 doesnt install on Python 3, so I think the minimum
>   should be at least 0.1.1.
>
> However I see that cryptography requires pyasn1>=0.1.8 , so it is
>   likely most people will be using that soon.